# React - "Forward" event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple input fields. When something is entered, I want to call the same function from all input fields. To know from which control the event was fired, I have created this code. This works fine, but actually, I want to forward the `event` to get access to `event.target.value` property. This is my component in short:

```
class FreightList extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           filters : [],
       };
       this.handleIdKeyUp = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this, event, 'Id');
       this.handleCompanyKeyUp = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this, event, 'Company');
   }

   onFiltersKeyUpHandler(event,filterName) {
     //do something
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <input type="text" ref="filtersId" onKeyUp={this.handleIdKeyUp.bind(this)} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
         <input type="text" ref="filtersCompany" onKeyUp={this.handleCompanyKeyUp.bind(this)} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
      )
   }
}
```

The issue now is, that in the method `onFiltersKeyUpHandler` the `event.target` property is `null`. I'm sure, this code

```
this.handleIdKeyUp = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this, event, 'Id');
```

is not valid to "forward" the `event` parameter, which should be received by `handleIdKeyUp`. So how can I forward the `event` parameter to `onFiltersKeyUpHandler` to get access to `event.target.value`?

Comment: you are binding event and `id` in your constructor `this.handleIdKeyUp = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this, event, 'Id');` so at that time obiously it will be null. you need to pass it when you are calling it

Comment: So I can do this?    handleIdKeyUp(event) {
    this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this, event, 'Id', event.target.value);
   }

Comment: you can do it simply like: 
this.handleIdKeyUp = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this);

and input side:
onKeyUp={(event) => {this.handleIdKeyUp(event, "id") }}

Comment: @dns_nx I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to bind the method to `this` in the constructor. Instead use arrow function as below. Further, use the arrow function in the `onKeyUp` event as well.

```
class FreightList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filters : [],
        };
    }

    onFiltersKeyUpHandler = (event, filterName) => {
        //do something
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <input type="text" ref="filtersId" onKeyUp={(e) => this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler(e, 'Id')} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
             <input type="text" ref="filtersCompany" onKeyUp={(e) => this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler(e, 'Company')} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: public class fields (aka: the arrow function) still have to be transpiled and are still only in a proposal state. while it is the solution i use myself, it isn't actually valid javascript yet. Also: you don't have to use it here since the function itself will be run within the lexical context since you are creating arrow functions in your render call.

Comment: Actually it is standardized (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions) and supported by modern browsers as well (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/arrowfunctiones6/) As for the legacy browsers, you an use Babel (https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-arrow-functions/)

Comment: yes, arrow functions are. class fields aren't: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields (stage 3)

Answer (score 1):

## edit

After seeing everybody implement the same component, let's do it properly :-)

```
class FreightList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filters: []
    };
    // reason to bind it in the constructor and not in the render function, is that it will otherwise be re-bound every render call. 
    // This means that every component using the function will have to re-render, since the props changed (the function reference changes)
    this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this);
  }
  onFiltersKeyUpHandler (event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const filterName = target.name;
    // ... handle stuff
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="Id" onKeyUp={this.onFiltersKeyupHandler} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
        <input type="text" name="Company" onKeyUp={this.onFiltersKeyupHandler} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding event and id in your constructor this.handleIdKeyUp = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this, event, 'Id'); so at that time obiously it will be null. you need to pass it when you are calling it

```
class FreightList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filters: [],
    };
    this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler = this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onFiltersKeyUpHandler(event, filterName) {
    console.log(event.target.value, filterName)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onKeyUp={(e) => this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler(e, 'ID')} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
        <input type="text" onKeyUp={(e) => this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler(e, 'Company')} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
        </div>
        )
  }
}
```

This is much simpler and you wont even need `refs`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer yet another way to do this.  You can also partially apply the `filterName`:

```
class FreightList extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           filters : [],
       };
   }

   onFiltersKeyUpHandler = filterName => event => {
     //do something
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <input type="text" ref="filtersId" onKeyUp={this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler("ID"} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
         <input type="text" ref="filtersCompany" onKeyUp={this.onFiltersKeyUpHandler("Company")} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: elegant solution. Keep in mind though: every re-render, you're creating new functions, which is a bad practice. ( for instance: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-arrow-functions-and-bind-in-reacts-render-are-problematic-f1c08b060e36 )

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" ref="filtersId" onKeyUp={(event) => {this.handleIdKeyUp(this, event)}} className="form-control minWidth50px" />
```

This should solve it.

Comment: this doesnt work. the `onKeyUp` event now returns a newly bound function. However, the `handleIdKeyUp` function won't be executed, it will just be bound.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/stack26/69z2wepo/99056/ see this fiddle It will work.

Comment: yes, because that code is different on the `onKeyUp`: `onKeyUp={() => this.fn.bind(this)}` vs `onKeyUp={this.fn.bind(this)}`

Comment: one question @DoXicK i was able to get event and id also in the onFiltersKeyUpHandler, I pasted the same code in fiddle. Then where dns_nx  was getting stuck

Comment: paste a new fiddle and i'll take a look at it :-)